# Sitecore Helper to render SXA Component inside cshtml

Tags: sxa, razor

I need to render the `Social Media Share` component in the `cshtml` of `Cloned Search Results`, is there a Sitecore Helper to render a component in the view? I am using `SXA 1.8` so I know that we have the ability to render a component inside a `rendering variant`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have 2 main options:

#### Use a placeholder

In your razor view, just add a placeholder, then in the Experience Editor, your marketers/editors can add the `Social Media Share` module to that.

Pros - its nice and easy, give flexibility too if you wanted to add anything else.
Cons - the editors have to remember to add the component every time.

#### Render the component inline

You can also use the Sitecore Html helper to render a component:

```
@Html.Sitecore().Rendering("<your rendering definition item id>", new { DataSource = "<your datasource item id>" })
```

Add the item Id of the `Social Media Share` component as the first parameter. You will also need to create a datasource item for that component and you add the DataSource item Id to that too.

You can also add parameters for things like Caching:

```
@Html.Sitecore().Rendering("<your rendering definition item id>", new { DataSource = "<your datasource item id>", Cacheable = true, CacheKey = "create a cache key", Cache_VaryByData = true })
```

Pros - again, its simple to do, the content editors don't have to remember to add any extra components on the page
Cons - you are reliant on a content item always being there. If that gets deleted, you will not get any warnings, this component will just fail.

Comment: Hey Richard, do you have any idea how I can preselect a specific rendering variant when I render an sxa component inline?

Comment: @Bgl86 please open a new question for that to be answered